# Add icons to TabItems

Tags: android

I am having trouble displaying the icons in tabsitem. They are displayed in the xml but not when the application runs.

This is the xml code. You can see that there are android:icon in the TabItem tag but it does not appears at the aplication screen.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tabicon_principal"
        android:text="Left" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tabicon_radio"
        android:text="Left2" />


</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

This is the tabsPager.java code:

```
public class tabsPager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    
    String [] titles = {"Inicio", "Radio"};

    public tabsPager (FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);

    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return titles[position];
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
                return fragment;
            case 1:
                BlankFragment4 fragment4 = new BlankFragment4();
                return fragment4;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: does it work if you set the ``TabLayout``'s height to ``wrap_content``?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you need to set the icons in code. There are two ways to use a `TabLayout`

- define all the tabs as a complete layout, and react to events like a tab being selected
- use an adapter and create the tabs dynamically

You're using the second option, which is why you have to provide the tab titles - the adapter is generating tabs dynamically. So you have to set them all up in code, including the icons. From [the docs:](https://material.io/develop/android/components/tabs#using-tabs)

> Further customization of the dynamically-created TabItems (such as setting icons) needs to be done separately:

```
val tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(index)
tab?.icon = drawable
```

So yeah, I'm assuming the ones you add in XML just get discarded as soon as you set the adapter on the `TabLayout`. You could keep them and use the `OnTabSelectedListener` approach, and use that to control a ViewPager, but obviously just setting up an array of icon resource IDs and applying those to what you have is easier